# partition before installing Ubuntu on 2nd hard disk

Tags: 14.04

I'm an new to Linux. my primary OS is Windows 7. But I want Ubuntu for bioinformatics purposes. So I have bought a new sata HDD (2TB) and have inserted it in the computer and have not yet turned the computer back on. I have the ubuntu dvd (iso file).

My query is should I first turn on the machine in windows to format the newly added drive,then shut down the machine and after that put the ubuntu iso DVD and turn on machine again to install ubuntu on second hard disk?

Or should I simply put the dvd now to directly create partition on second hard disk and install ubuntu on it simultanously?

Since I am unfamiliar with poking around with the OS, I would appreciate any help lent.

Comment: The installer on the DVD can create partitions, in fact, whatever partitions you create on Windows for Ubuntu, will be formatted by Ubuntu anyway. You might disconnect the Windows HDD as a precaution.